# How to generate IP cores with access to hardware in vivado

Tags: vhdl, xilinx, vga, vivado

I am looking for some guide on how create an IP-Core in Vivado which make integrate the hardware. I want to create a IP-Core which should act as an driver for VGA port. The problem is how to create it such that it auto connect to the right port, and how do I declare which ports it has to be connected to?

The board I am using is a ZYBO which has an `Zynq 7010` processor.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you give the ip core pins that can be routed out to the top level module, then assign the pins to the physical chip pins with a constraints file. There is no automated way to do this. The pins are going to be board dependent, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There are different IPs in vivado. 
 - The first for internal hw IPs such as multipliers, ramblocks etc. Those don't need external connection.

- The second ones are IPs to communicate with IO pins those pins can be located anywhere on the FFPGA.
- The 3rd type are the ones using dedicated hardware associated to specific hard IPs and pins, like high speed up transceivers or XADC. Those get connected to the right pin when creating the IPs.
- The 4th type are IPs that are not connected to any internal HW module of the FPGA. Can be placed anywhere and if they use any IOs those must be placed by the user.

Your VGA IP is of the last type. You have to find the proper IO on your board and connect them to the right name on your IP.